# How to make card resposive

Tags: html, css

I'm using boostrap, and I'm making a flipping animation card inside a row (col-lg-12), the problem is that when I resize the screen the card doesn't act "responsive"

```css
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  perspective: 800;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}

.flip .card {
  width: 270px;
  height: 178px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.flip .card .face {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flip .card .img {
  position: relaitve;
  width: 270px;
  height: 178px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.flip .card .back {
  padding-top: 10%;
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}

.inner {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="porosity" class="card">
  <div class="face front">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
      <p>Porosity</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="face back">
    <div class="inner text-center">
      <p>Permeable to fluids, permeable to outside influences.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Full code: https://codepen.io/elunap/pen/rYJEVW

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could you be more specific, for me it's responsive what is your issue ?

Comment: Start off by removing explicit `width` properties declared on `.flip .card .front` & `.flip .card`. Horizontally align `.flip .card .front` by declaring `left` and `right` properties, e.g: `left: 0; right: 0;` - since this is an `absolute` positioned element this will be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that when you resize screen the flipping card stay at the left while the others stay at center, if you want to make the flipping card stay at center like the others, you have to add `margin: auto` as follow:

```
.flip .card {
    /* New property added */
    margin: auto
}
```

check the updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/AlaaMh/pen/ZardvK), hope this what you want.

Comment: I don't get how CSS can sometimes be this...tricky, I guess I need to practice more, thanks a lot!

Comment: in most cases, when you want to center a fixed width `div`, you might add `margin: auto` to it, you're most welcome bro!